# slick slider проблема верстки

Tags: html, css, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток! у меня возникла проблема с версткой слайдера а именно с выделенной частью , слайдер она как бы залазит под активные слайды, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли это выполнить используя slick slider!

Comment: скинь сайт где размещен слайдер

Comment: @GENESIS код с примером проблемы должен быть прямо в тексте вопроса, без каких-либо сторонних сайтов

Comment: мне кажется там проблема с css, и делением слайдов по ширине экрана

Comment: там проблема сверстать сам слайдер

Answer (score 0):

Проверяй стоит ли в цсс параметры для img скорее всего тебе надо либо же подходящего размера фото либо же ограничение делать, к примеру

```
.slick-slider {
  img {max-width: 100%;}
}
```

Возможно и в чем то другом проблема, скиньте свой код.